# missing documentation in java doc from maven

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I have an project Maven with ejb/web/ear projects.
When I am trying to generete javadoc, the documentation from the source packages is generating correct, but the it does not generate javadoc from the "Test Packages".[looks of structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joT0J.jpg) 
[Looks of options maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoG2B.jpg)
Could anyone give me an advice how to reach javadoc from Test Packages?

Comment: right click on project, go to run > java doc (click it), it will create the source java doc for you, but this will possible in maven project.

Comment: @ArifMustafa I added the looks of menu maven - I don't have such option

Comment: Okay let me flash some more light here on my earlier comment to illustrate more on the way to perform,  Right click on Maven Project, goto menu option Run As => Maven generate-sources (click it), so now Maven will generate the source doc for you in the target section, but this will only happen on maven project as I illustrated earlier.

Comment: when yiu want maven to do this make sure the physical directory structure conforms to its conventions: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html and that the javadoc plugin is in your pom: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/test-javadocs.html - the screenshots dont really tell anything what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have javadoc structure in the Test add some javadoc comments

```
/**

*/
```

in the test and try `mvn javadoc:javadoc`

Hope that helps,
Kiril